# Cannot remove JDK – /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, java, dpkg

When I try to remove Java with `sudo apt-get remove jdk1.8.0-40`
I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  jdk1.8.0-40
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 245 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 231488 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jdk1.8.0-40 (1.8.040-1) ...
find: `/usr/java/*': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-40 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8.0-40
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of  `ls -1 /var/cache/apt/archives/*jdk*`:

```
openjdk-7-jre_7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
```

Output of `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all jdk1.8.0-40`:

```
(Reading database ... 231488 files and directories currently installed.)
removing jdk1.8.0-40 (1.8.040-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-40 (--purge):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8.0-40
```

When trying the edit I get this:

```
(Reading database ... 231488 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jdk1.8.0-40 (1.8.040-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: Permission denied
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-40 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8.0-40
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: try this first, and then try to remove again,
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure jdk1.8.0-40`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a file in that folder and executing the uninstall command then:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/java
sudo touch /usr/java/aa
sudo touch /usr/sbin/alternatives
sudo apt-get remove jdk1.8.0-40
```

#### EDIT:

---

Try this: 
    echo "" | sudo tee /var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm

Comment: Now i get this: Removing jdk1.8.0-40 (1.8.040-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-40 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8.0-40
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: When running sudo dpkg-reconfigure i get:  /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: jdk1.8.0-40 is broken or not fully installed

Comment: Please update your post with the output of this command: `ls /var/cache/apt/archives/ | grep -i jdk`

Comment: Now i have updated the post.

Comment: Try this: `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all jdk1.8.0-40`

Comment: Dosent Work Output in main post.

Comment: Let's try the edit to my answer

Comment: Then i get permission denied error specific in main post.

Comment: Try this: `echo "" | sudo tee /var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm` and then uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

> > ```
> > /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
> > ```
>
> There is no `/usr/sbin/alternatives` in Debian, Ubuntu, etc. Debian
>   clones. Instead there is `/usr/bin/update-alternatives`.
>
> I suggest a temporary symbolic link to work around the badly converted
>   RPM package:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p /usr/sbin
> ln -sT -- /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/alternatives
> ```

<sup>([source](//stackoverflow.com/a/33636256/2461638))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

this for error of 'E: The package jre1.8.0-51 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq jre1.8.0-51