# I have problem executing apt-get

Tags: 14.04, apt

My Ubuntu Version is 14.04 Kylin. I deleted something wrongly when I tried to remove Java. And since that I got problem executing `apt-get`.

```
kael@ASUS:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  jdk1.8.0-45
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 65 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 245 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 258011 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jdk1.8.0-45 (1.8.045-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-45.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-45.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-45 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8.0-45
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597015/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)

Answer (score 2):

If all other options fail, do what i did.
other info, i got myself here by trying to install the rpm jdk8 pachage on linux mint 17(ubuntu)

```
sudo rm -ri /usr/java/
```

it will ask for password 
then ask to make sure you want to delete that directory. press "y" and enter/return

then open /var/lib/dpkg/info/ as root and delete any files with 
"jdk1.8.0-xx.xxxx"
once done deleting run

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all jdk1.8.0-45
```

if you are trying to install jdk 8.
this page will be of help because it worked for me.(linux mint 17 cinnamon 64bit)
http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the missing file as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597015/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1). Follow:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/java
sudo touch /usr/java/aa
sudo touch /usr/sbin/alternatives
sudo apt-get remove jdk1.8.0-40
echo "" | sudo tee /var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm
```

Then un-intall  java by:

`sudo dpkg --purge --force-all jdk1.8.0-45`

Comment: what;s the error?

Comment: I tried this one, but it was not working... But I create the missing file and did 
cp /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/alternatives

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `jdk1.8.0-45`'s `dpkg`'s post-removal script exits due to an error happening during its execution (probably due to something you have deleted); this leads `dpkg` to exit as well.

One solution is to lead the post-removal script to not exit upon errors; this can be done by unsetting the `e` attribute in the `sh` instance in which is going to be executed, i.e. by removing the `set -e` line in the script itself (the script's path should be `/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-45.postrm`).

Once done this, you should be able to run `sudo apt-get install -f` without errors.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I have already made it working now.

Comment: @YueXu Do you mind adding your own answer to this question and mark it as accepted? This way users reading this question may know which method worked for you without blindly try the others first.

Comment: cp /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/alternatives

Comment: @YueXu your solution worked fine!!