# Ubuntu DPKG error

Tags: dpkg, jdk

```
E: The package jdk1.8.0-45 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Above is the message i get while trying to run the upgrade command in Ubuntu as follows :

```
sudo-apt-get upgrade
```

Problem may be since i deleted the /java directory.

Comment: Duplicate of unresolved question http://askubuntu.com/questions/626017/apt-get-cancel-pending-task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove Java, do this:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all jdk1.8.0-45
```

(it did not work for the question owner, alternative solution below)

- Execute

  ```
  sudo rm -ri /usr/java/
  ```
- Open /var/lib/dpkg/info/ as root and delete any files with "jdk1.8.0-xx.xxxx"
- Once done deleted run

  ```
  sudo dpkg -r --force-all jdk1.8.0-45
  ```
- This should have removed Java completely. Source: [I have problem executing apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619889/i-have-problem-executing-apt-get)

This will install Oracle Java 8 (closed source):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Will you explain please that it is Oracle java and what these commands are about.

Comment: still getting the below error when trying to the third command for java8 installation :                                                                                                      abhishek@abhishek-SVE15118FNB:~/Documents$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package jdk1.8.0-45 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: even the purge asks me to reinstall the package before removing it due to inconsistencies.

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: /var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-45.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-45.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-45 (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8.0-45