# Unable to install anything using apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, jdk, alien

I looked through some threads and couldn't find a solution, apologies if this is a duplicate.

After messing up an installation of some package (see below), attempting to install anything yields:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sl Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 linux-headers-4.2.0-34 linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
 jdk1.8.0-77
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 sl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/26.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 269 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 240329 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jdk1.8.0-77 (1.8.077-fcs-1) ...
find: `/usr/java/*': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-77.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-77.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-77 (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
jdk1.8.0-77
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What broke everything: I tried installing jdk8 on my Ubuntu Gnome machine. I did the following:

1. Downloaded the relevant .rpm from [Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), used `alien --scripts` to convert it to a .deb, then installing it using `dpkg -i`. That didn't work (it spent some time installing and then complained about some installation script. Not entirely sure what the exact messege was).
2. Followed [this guide](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/). When reached the `apt-get install` part, the installation eventually fails.

I tried `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get autoclean`, and also `dpkg -P jdk1.8.0-77`.

It is worth mentioning that after one of the installs a folder with a lock icon on it (in the file browser) that was named jdk1.8.0-77/ was created in the same folder as the .rpm. I deleted that folder because I thought I downloaded it.

Edit: `apt-get install -f` yields

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   linux-headers-4.2.0-34 linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic 
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them. 

The following packages will be REMOVED:
   jdk1.8.0-77 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 269 MB disk space will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y 
(Reading database ... 240329 files and directories currently installed.) 
Removing jdk1.8.0-77 (1.8.077-fcs-1) ... 
find: `/usr/java/*': No such file or directory 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-77.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory /var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-77.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory 
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-77 (--remove):  
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127 Errors were encountered while processing:  jdk1.8.0-77
```

Edit 2: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619889/i-have-problem-executing-apt-get) post seems extremely relevant. I tried following the advice given there (`touch`ing `/usr/sbin/alternatives` but the script now fails on a call to `find`)

Edit 3: A reboot (and a pseudorandom combination of `apt-get autoremove` and `dpkg -P` plus some meddling with the script seem to have solved the issue so far.