# Error while installing or updating anything

Tags: java, uninstall, dpkg, jre, postscript

Since I was trying to install Java manually which I couldn't doing I have been having these errors while trying to install or update anything through terminal or update manager.

```
(Reading database ... 203927 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jre1.8.0-51 (1.8.051-1) ...
find: `/usr/java/*': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-51.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jre1.8.0-51 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-51
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i tried 
`sudo apt-get autoclean`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
sudo dpkg -P jre1.8.0-51
```

none of them worked , i always get that error at the end.
can anyone help?

Comment: How did you install Java?

Comment: i installed by downloading the rpm file on oracle page, used the alien command to extract the rpm file and the dpkg -i commando to install the deb file. but i found the solution now,  just removed the file which was giving error:  /var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-51.postrm  //// its working fine now, but thanks for answering me.

Comment: Good idea, write an answer. You have my upvote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot remove JDK – /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597015/cannot-remove-jdk-usr-sbin-alternatives-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Just removed the file which was giving error.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-51.postrm
```

That is no problem, because I want to remove the package anyway.