# Broken JRE installation, any advice how to fix?

Tags: package-management, java

It's a long bogus saga to explain how I got here, but I've got a bad partial install of JRE 1.8.0-71 on my Ubuntu machine, and `--force-remove-reinstreq` isn't working:

```
# sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq jre1.8.0-71  
(Reading database ... 633119 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jre1.8.0-71 (1.8.071-1) ...
find: `/usr/java/*': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-71.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jre1.8.0-71 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-71
```

Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597015/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer: make a symlink from /usr/bin/update-alternatives to /usr/sbin/alternatives, use dpkg --purge, then delete the symlink:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635075/remove-broken-java-installation-linux